# Radians and Degrees Preference

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal-processing, signal-theory

In electronics engineering which is the better unit to work with radians or degrees?What are the advantages those 2 unit provides?

Comment: We advise you to wait a day or two before accepting answers. That way you will give everyone a chance to answer and you will encourage others to answer. You can unaccept at any time.

Comment: Sounds like asking for an opinion, to me. But, what it al comes down to, is, really, whichever makes *you* feel more comfortable. Personally, when I need results, degrees are preferable due to the large extent of possible divisions. If it's symbolic, I prefer radians, they seem to make more sense in trigonometric relations. For you, flip the coin and keep to that choice. If it suits you, fine, if not, change it.

Comment: In 'electronic engineering', I usually work with circles, and binary subdivisions thereof. Degrees are for man-interface, radians are for maths function interface, binary fractions of a circle work well if I'm digitising phase, running COORDIC algorithms etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radians almost always. Granted, you have to get used to doing trig in units of 2 pi, but once you get over that hurdle, it makes all sorts of math simpler. Sine and cosine are expressed as variations on $$sin(\omega) = Re\text{ } {e^{j\omega}}$$ and its derivative, which is much cleaner than needing to throw factors of 2 pi around.

Degrees have their uses, but generally only in terms of user interfaces, such as compasses and indicating shaft rotations, and specifying phase shifts. Once you get into actual calculation, radians are king.